# Running Cumulative sum of 1d NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like

`x=np.array([1,2,3,4])`

I want to create another numpy array y which is the cumulative sum of x, so that

`y=np.array([1,3,6,10])`

What is a good num-Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
y = np.cumsum(x)
```

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Comment: @Dan , Can I get the result in-place. I want the result is also in `x`, not another array `y`

Answer (score 8):

Another option is:

```
y = np.add.accumulate(x)
```

which is often times faster than `np.cumsum` even though the documentation says they are equivalent.

Comment: I would like to say that I also tested this and accumulate is slightly faster on my system too: %timeit np.add.accumulate(range(20000000)) ---> 3.06 s ± 40.1 and for cumsum I get 3.08 s ± 24.7 ms